# How to handle two implementations of the same service

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I have a python project where we are using DDD and we are also using dependency injection. In that project, I have the following interface for a data source:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class DTODataSourceInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(id: int) -> DTO:
        …
```

And another one for a repository:

```py
class RepositoryInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(id: int) -> DTO:
        …
```

The repository implementation depending on that data source interface, is something like this:

```py
class Repository(RepositoryInterface):
    def __init__(
        self,
        data_source: DTODataSourceInterface,
        cache_data_source: DTODataSourceInterface
    ):
        self.data_source = data_source
        self.cache_data_source = cache_data_source
  
    def get(id: int) -> Entity:
       …
```

Now, as you can see, we use the same data source interface twice: the first one for our “slow” storage (some database) and the other one for caching (something like redis, memcache).

In our dependency injector we register one implementation for interface, so the `DTODataSourceInterface` gets mapped only to one implementation! We cannot map both the database data source and the redis data source (for instance) to the same interface, which makes imposible to call our dependency injector like this:

```py
Inject(RepositoryInterface)
```

In fact, you could execute that, but you would get the same implementation for both parameters in the `Repository` implementation, what is something we obviously do not want.

I have not added the implementation for our dependency injector because is custom made for us.

So, that’s my problem. I have been thinking about allow our DI implementation to allow interfaces to have more than one implementation, but I do not know how would I resolve them, like, how to distinguish when to use one or the other (maybe based on the parameter name? Don’t like the sound of that to be honest).

Any experience on this?

Comment: In PHP selecting between multiple services defined for the same interface is commonly done using the parameter name.  I understand the reluctance to basically add parameter names as dependencies in your configuration but in practice it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find a solution is that you have 2 different interfaces, one for **slow access** and one for **fast access**. They could share the same base interface, that means that the could be empty themselves, but both should exists because they solve 2 different problems.

Moreover, having 2 of them allows you to extend each one with exactly the needs that are going to arise for that interface, without touching the other one. For example: your **fast interface** is required to return an extended object, that initially wasn't expected. You simply implement it, and you're finish. The **slow interface** remains instead unchanged because this particular function, or requirement, doesn't apply to it.

On the other side, if later your **slow interface** requires a new *query* to return some data, you could implement it without having to worry about how you would implement it in the **fast interface**, simply because you don't have it.

Remember: keep it simple and one responsibility for each class/interface. You could 'reduce' the code, sharing the common parts (defining a base interface, for example), but it should always remain clear which problem you're going to  solve without mixing the responsibilities.